# Is it normal for fs.rename to not update mtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

In nodejs, I use fs.rename to rename a file on the filesystem.

The file gets renamed, as expected, but as far as I can tell it does not update the mtime.  Is this normal?  If I want to update mtime, do I have to do it manually by setting the date?

Comment: Renaming a file is not a modification of the file. The contents are not affected. Only the directory entry is changed.